# Send flag to python program to exit, in its own time. Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am writing a long-term prime search program, that can be closed and reopened with a system of writing out found primes to file. I do not want help with the algs, but I need a method of killing the program *only* when it gets to the end of the main loop i.e. it has **fully** found a prime. The relevant parts of code are below.

```
check = 7

def isprime(n):
  #do...

while True:
  if isprime(check):
    print(check, "is prime")
  else:
    print(check, "isn't prime")
  check += 2
```

This code will not work, but it is a good template as my question is not specific to my program. I want to `break` out of the main `while True` loop, **only** when at the end of it. The only solution I could think of, which is not practical at all, is at the end of `while True` I read in a file and if it is "stop" I `break`. However, I don't want to have to type into a file when I want to stop, and reading a file is a time-waster.

I am sorry if this question appears opinion based, but I tried my best.

Comment: If you don't want to write to a file (as you stated in the question), then the other option I know would be to use threading, with the main thread listening for `KeyboardInterupt` signals while the secondary thread does the prime-calculation work.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not understanding your question correctly, but what does it mean to have "fully found a prime"? Are you saying that you don't want to kill the program when the code is in the middle of `isprime()` algorithm? As in, if you send the kill signal at some point, you want the `isprime()` to finish if the program was in the middle of it, print the results, THEN close?

Comment: Absolutely - I want it to finish `isprime` and preferably then get to the end of `while True`. I apologise for wording

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threading is a good option as suggested by others. However, you can have a lighter option of using a try/except catching a keyboard interrupt and using an `end` flag. If the kill signal is sent during the `isprime()` calculation, the current calculation for `isprime()` will be killed, `check` will not be incremented by 2, the `except` block will execute to switch the `end` flag to `True`, and then you will re-start the `isprime` calculation for the previous `check` until you are done, increment, then `break`. The advantage of this method is that it is lighter than having the overhead of creating a new thread (which is small compared to creating a new process) and that it is easier to debug than a multithreaded script. However, the multithreaded option is fine to debug if the code will not get much bigger and you won't be needing other threads as a part of the same script.

```
end = False
while True:
    try:
        if isprime(check):
            print(check, "is prime")
        else:
            print(check, "isn't prime")
        check += 2
        if end: 
            break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('end signal received')
        end = True
```

Comment: I think this solution is good, but does not solve OP's problem of wanting to avoid exiting during the middle of his `check()` function... If a `KeyboardInterrupt` is thrown at any point, the program will exit immediately (potentially in the middle of his function)

Comment: I disagree. If a KeyboardInterrupt is thrown, it will be caught by the `except` statement, and the program will continue because the exception was caught.

Comment: Hmm I guess maybe you're right, although I'm not positive. I messed around with your code, and I *think* that it does abort the calculation halfway, but then goes back and redoes the calculation in another loop where upon reaching the end it does exit as expected. I think if OP is OK with the ramifications of doing this, then your answer is indeed more lightweight than using threads

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to create a prime and another function to listen to `KeyboardInterrupt` signals as Ralf commented. In your prime function at the end do a

```
if not Keyboard_thread.is_alive():
    break
```

This will have your code check that it has not been stopped only at the **end** of the cycle, thereby avoiding terminating your program mid calculation. Threading documentation is at https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html for more depth! essentially though you want to do something like

```
t = threading.Thread(target=your_function, args=[your_list_of_parameters](arguments are optional))
t.start()
```

Sorry if you already know threads, but it wasn't part of your post so I will assume you do not.

You can call `t.join()` to end your thread that is waiting for keyboard interrupts (specifying a timeout), or have your function come to an end by breaking. Doing so will then flag your other thread (the one checking if `keyboard_thread.is_alive()` that it should also break out of its loop. Note: threads only run until the end of the function you assign them, so for instance if your function is:

```
def new_function():
    print("hey")
```

If you assign a thread to this function, the thread will print "hey" once and then terminate itself upon reaching the end of the function. Feel free to leave a comment if something I said is unclear!